# NPM ERR When typing run npm dev in vscode terminal

Tags: reactjs, node.js, react-native, npm

What I've done to solve this problem is placing node.js in my environments. I was successful in running run nmp dev on another laptop I own. In the browser I saw the logo Vite and React. But on the present laptop I'm using the browser doesn't even open when I type npm run dev. When I type in the browser localhost:5173 I get "unable to connect" in firefox. I read the answers to my question and tried the suggestions by uninstalling node.js and reinstalling it.In VS Code My folder is REACT and my project name is swydell. Here is a snippet of the structure:
npm ERR! C:\Users\allwa\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2024-03-13T16_09_46_713Z-debug-0.log
PS C:\Users\allwa\OneDrive\Desktop\REACT\swydell>